# Site for accepting user photos (crowdsourcing)

Tags: webapp-rec, photo-sharing

We would like to start accepting user-contributed photos for our website and events in our area. Ideally we'd like to be able to say "email uploads@photosite.com" as well as a web interface where users can upload their photos, or perhaps share via Facebook etc.

We don't want the photos to be published right away of course, as we'll need to vet and choose the best ones, but we would like them to go directly into our photo account so we can easily publish them. We have both a SmugMug account and a Flickr account but haven't been able to determine if this can be done and where.

Comment: I'm not sure if this might be better asked on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/. Are you asking for existing sites that do this or advice on how to do it? If the former then here is OK, if the latter then Webmasters is the place.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am indeed looking for a web site that is designed to do this that we can sign up for. something that gives us a public input for user submitted content. currently we are just giving out an email address for people to send images. this email account fills up fast, and it would be great if there were a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Picasa](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/09/add-photos-by-email-in-picasa-web.html), [Facebook](http://lifehacker.com/5321149/quickly-upload-photos-and-video-to-facebook-via-email) and [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/help/mobile/#33) all offer ways to upload public photos via email.

If you're looking for a simple hosting site to view photos submitted in private, simply adjust the privacy settings for each of these sites.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress.com allows you to [submit posts via email](http://en.support.wordpress.com/post-by-email/). While it would be a bad idea to publish the submission address, when you receive an email submission you want to publish, you can just forward it there.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing SmugMug account has an [email upload capacity](http://www.smugmug.com/help/camera-phones-and-email). You can also put up a very simple web form that uses [the API](http://wiki.smugmug.net/display/API/Home) to do an upload. I whipped up something like that for a book we were building using the 3rd party [phpSmug wrapper](http://phpsmug.com/) in a couple hours over a weekend.

---

*Disclaimer*: I work for SmugMug.

Answer (score 0):

This is something called "user generated content"

I know [FileMobile](http://filemobile.com) has an application that does what you are looking for including pre and post moderation.